# Display one row in report by concat Inner join query

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT t.TRAINER_ID,
              t.LAST_NAME,
       t.ID_NUM,
            t.language,
       --t.Service,
       -- t.Unit,
       --t.Rate,
       (TSI.service || ' - ' || TSI.unit || ' - ' || TSI.rate) INFO  -- This is the join table I want one row to display in the report

  FROM LMS$TRAINERS T
  inner   join Trainer_service_info TSI
  on T.trainer_id = TSI.trainer_id
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID AND status = 'A'
```

The above code displays the below results

```
Trainer_id  Name    ID              Lanuage             INFO             
1000018582  Twynam  5304025007080   Afrikaans:English   8 - 1 - 150     
1000018582  Twynam  5304025007080   Afrikaans:English   7 - 2 - 700
```

I would like it to display

```
Trainer_id  Name    ID              Lanuage             INFO             
1000018582  Twynam  5304025007080   Afrikaans:English   8 - 1 - 150 - 7 - 2 - 700
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? If it's 11g or above, you should look at the LISTAGG function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with listagg

```
SELECT t.TRAINER_ID,
          t.LAST_NAME,
   t.ID_NUM,
        t.language,
   --t.Service,
   -- t.Unit,
   --t.Rate,
   TSI.INFO  -- This is the join table I want one row to display in the report
  FROM LMS$TRAINERS T
  inner   join (select trainer_id,listagg(service || ' - ' || unit || ' - ' || rate,' - ') within group (order by trainer_id) as info from Trainer_service_info group by trainer_id) TSI
  on T.trainer_id = TSI.trainer_id;
```